# MacBook External Monitor full screen drops when lid closes

Tags: macbook-pro

When using MacBook Pro on Safari using YouTube with Full screen, when using an external monitor, and close the MacBook lid, it works, but when I use Firefox browser, YouTube, full screen and close the MacBook lid, the external monitor doesn’t show full screen.

Comment: This sounds like a Firefox problem because full screen videos work with the lid closed when using Safari.  Have you checked the Mozilla support groups?